# Open and process all text files in directory in Unix using C++

Tags: c++, file-io, directory, bucket, bucket-sort

Good Evening,

I am very stumped on a problem concerning opening and processing text files within a directory. The directory holds 10,000 .txt files, each with a sentence of two of text. The problem I need to solve requires me going through each file, and bucket sort them based on the length. I would need to separate them into 10 different buckets. I have really no clue how to go about this, and have not found anything useful on the internet. I have no problem opening a single file, but how do I open 10,000, without knowing their names, and then sort them based on length? Any help at all would be appreciated, as I am very confused.

Edit 1: I have written the code to get the names of the files, put them into a vector, then opening them by moving through the vector. However, I still cannot move each string into a vector, then bucket sort the vector. I don't think I can use a library function for the sort, I must write the bucket sort function myself. So how would I bucket sort a vector of strings based upon the length of the strings? Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Start with [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir)

Comment: First open and read the directory. This will give you information, including the names, of all the files in the directory. [Open and read all files](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream). Place the file contents into [a std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Sort the vector with [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)